# Upgrading from visual studio 2005 to visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio

Our development team is planning to upgrade from visual studio 2005 to visual studio 2010 -- skipping out visual studio 2008.

Most of the projects are VB ASP.NET projects and using SQL Server 2008 as the database.

Does anyone know if VS 2005  projects will upgrade seamlessly to VS 2010, or should they first be upgraded to VS 2008? Are there any gotchas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will upgrade just like normal, no need to go through VS2008 first. I've even upgraded VC++ 6 projects straight to VS2010 without issue! (well, except for the C++ non-conformance problems inherent in any VC6 project)

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to go thru 2008,
however, for any large codebase I have seen, Visual Studio upgrade never passed without a fight.

Answer (score 0):

I personally upgraded from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010 without problems.  I would imagine they wouldn't expect everybody to be upgrading from Visual Studio 2008 and should have support for Visual Studio 2005.  I know it's not much of an answer but you could always just backup your project(s) using Visual Studio 2010 and see if there are any problems.  If not then all is good :)  If you have problems (which again, I don't see why you should, it should work seamlessly) you can try using Visual Studio 2008 beforehand.